# How to get JDBC working?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Since I found nothing on my specific problem at all, I guess it's a simple question, but I still can't figure it out. 
I prepared everything for a connection between java and mysql via j/connector, just like stated in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html), but the

```
ant create-mysql-database
```

fails with

```
BUILD FAILED 
/home/zynic/Documents/java/JDBCTutorial/build.xml:73: Class Not Found: JDBC driver 
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded
```

and I have no idea why. I set all the variables as the tutorial suggested, as you can see in the following, but still don't get it to work as intended.

*What's the (simple?) point I'm missing?*

Edit:
To sum the first comments up I am working on my own machine with Sabayon/Gentoo, and the build.xml is edited properly as well.

mysql-sample-properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<entry key="dbms">mysql</entry>
<entry key="jar_file">/home/zynic/Documents/java//JDBCTutorial.jar</entry>
<entry key="driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</entry> 
<entry key="database_name">testdb</entry> 
<entry key="user_name">root</entry> 
<entry key="password">root</entry> 
<entry key="server_name">localhost</entry> 
<entry key="port_number">3306</entry>
</properties>
```

mysql-build-properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="MySQL Properties" default="all" basedir=".">


<property name="JAVAC" value="/var/db/pkg/oracle-jdk-1.7.0.3/bin/javac"/>
<property name="JAVA" value="/var/db/pkg/oracle-jdk-1.7.0.3/bin/java"/>


<property name="PROPERTIESFILE" value="properties/mysql-sample-properties.xml"/>
<property name="MYSQLDRIVER" value="/var/db/pkg/jdbc-mysql-5.1.18/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar"/>

<path id="CLASSPATH">
<pathelement location="classes"/>
<pathelement location="${MYSQLDRIVER}"/>
<pathelement location="lib/JDBCTutorial.jar"/>
</path>

<property name="XALAN" value="/usr/share/xalan/lib/xalan.jar"/>

<property name="DB.VENDOR" value="mysql"/>
<property name="DB.DRIVER" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="DB.HOST" value="localhost"/>
<property name="DB.PORT" value="3306"/>
<property name="DB.SID" value="testdb"/>
<property name="DB.URL.NEWDATABASE" value="jdbc:mysql://${DB.HOST}:${DB.PORT}/?allowMultiQueries=true"/>
<property name="DB.URL" value="jdbc:mysql://${DB.HOST}:${DB.PORT}/${DB.SID}?allowMultiQueries=true"/>
<property name="DB.USER" value="root"/>
<property name="DB.PASSWORD" value="root"/>
<property name="DB.DELIMITER" value=";"/>

</project>
```

Comment: May be it's this line `<entry key="jar_file">/home/zynic/Documents/java//JDBCTutorial.jar</entry>`. Try removing the double `/`.

Comment: mh, good idea, but that wasn't it.

Comment: Try using `<classpath></classpath>`. And where's your ant script with the tasks defined?

Comment: It's the build.xml from the tutorial files. I'd upload it but with about 250 lines I think it's too huge.

Comment: Yeah don't do that. Just post the link.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html

Comment: If you have this part done properly in your example `<property
  name="ANTPROPERTIES"
  value="properties/mysql-build-properties.xml"/>

  <import file="${ANTPROPERTIES}"/>` I don't know what's wrong!

Comment: Yes, I did that, just made sure and checked again. Same here... :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you downloaded the mysql connector/j driver for the tutorial?

Comment: Yes, especially since I had to look up the path.

Comment: Fair enough. Is it accessible? Are you able to connect in an IDE? Have you tried starting from scratch just to see if you missed something and didn't realize it?

Comment: Yes, I tried three times so far.
How could I check that from an IDE?
What do you mean with 'accessible'?

Comment: He means whether you have the appropriate permission. But you probably do since you downloaded it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect:

```
<property name="MYSQLDRIVER" value="/var/db/pkg/jdbc-mysql-5.1.18/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar"/>
```

Note 5.1.**18** in the directory name and 5.1.**15** in the jar name.

Comment: That was a good tip. I corrected that as well, but it still doesn't work. Thanks anyways!